# collapsed menu background blurred

Tags: html, css

I was trying to find it somewhere, but couldn't find relevant one. can someone help me in this and let me know if it's actually possible?

I have a navigation bar, which on collapse has transparent background. it looks weird for now cause I the background (hero image) of the site is making the menu items unreadable. you can see it here, on smaller screen:
here you can find HTML: view-source:http://test.geradovana.lt/b2b/
and CSS: http://test.geradovana.lt/b2b/css/style.css

how should I edit the background for smaller screens to blur or make some frozen-icy effect for this image in the background while the menu is collapsing? I was trying to add the background (some % transparent) for menu, but it didn't give the effect.

thank you very much for help!

Answer (score 0):

Hmm this is almost a off-topic question since there is so many possible answers. But what I could recommend is to make another div inside the `container` class div. Immediate child of that div, which has CSS styles something like this:

```
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
top: 0;
left: 0;
-webkit-filter: blur(30px);
filter: blur(30px);
background-color: #000000;
opacity: 0.2;
```

You would also probably like to set the following CSS to remove the 1px white line on top of the dropdown:

```
@media (max-width: 1200px)
  .navbar-collapse {
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    box-shadow: none; /* This had value before and caused the white line */
  }
}
```

This will affect the page also on bigger screens but I don't think it's a bad thing necessarily. This will make the whole header stand out a little bit from the background. Also it will make the navigation links readable on smaller screens after it has turned into a "mobile" navigation.

Of course and it goes without saying please fiddle around with the opacity and blur to make it your own.